# Tinymce how to make the alternative description field for images required?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using tiny MCE version 5.8.2, sometimes the writers don't add the alternative description when they upload an image. So I would like to make the field required, so that to add the picture the alt must be filled.

I tried the [`a11y_advanced_options`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/image/#a11y_advanced_options), but it's not what I want, this check are done after the image is added, I want that the form is not submitable until the field is not filled.

[image]

I'm thinking about writing a plugin to do it, but I don't know if it's the right solution.

How would you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that might be effective, and make use of TinyMCE's existing APIs so you don't need to write anything custom, could be:

1. Use the A11ychecker [toggleaudit() method](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/premium/a11ychecker/#toggleaudit)
2. Pair this with a specific TinyMCE event, such as [NodeChange, BeforeGetContent, and Change](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/#handlingeditorevents) or similar event, like the click on the Save button.

The save button in the image dialog has a class of 'tox-button' and responds to the `click` event, so there may be a way to run the toggleaudit() method when these events happen. However, writing a short script to test this is reaching my knowledge limits.

It's a good question though, and quite possibly something that should be added as a design feature.

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe how a user upload an image

If you use a filemanager get the filename and post with window.parent.postMessage

The in the file_picker_callback function add

```
// Provide image and alt text for the image dialog
if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
  callback(details.content, {alt: details.info.substr(0, details.info.lastIndexOf('.'))});
}
```

Comment: The image can be uploaded directly or be just an url, I don't want to automatically fill the input, but I want to show a message to the user and ask him to chose the alt